# Replacing math expression String for evaluating with Java Script won't replace all ** incidences

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, eval

I'm trying to parse a math expression in order to evaluate it using `.eval`.

I coded:

```
function evaluarExpresion (fx, x) {

    fx = fx.replace("x", x)
    fx = fx.replace("e", "Math.E")
    fx = fx.replace("sin", "Math.sin")
    fx = fx.replace("tan", "Math.tan")
    fx = fx.replace("cos", "Math.cos")
    fx = fx.replace("pi", "Math.PI")
    fx = fx.replace("**", "^")
    return eval(fx)
}
```

However, when calling with **`(1^3)/(1+x**(1/2))`** for example it will fail as the replaces statement only turn the `fx` string into:

```
'(1^3)/(1+x**(1/2))'
```

So the `eval` statement throws:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`

How could I fix this or what's a best alternative (any library) for evaluating these such expressions (trigonometrics, sqrt, e, pi, etc) numerically?

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/693Cr/)

Comment: These kind of replacements are tricky: They blindly replace character sequences without checking if it's a whole word. For example the expression `exp(x)` would be replaced with `Math.Exp(x)`, and `ceil(x)` with `cMath.Eil(x)` because of a matching `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expression parser of [math.js](http://mathjs.org), like:

```
var math = mathjs();

var result = math.eval('(1^3)/(1+x^(1/2))', {x: 16}); // 0.2
```

One thing: math.js currently lacks bitwise operations as you use in your example. I'm not sure if in your example you actually intend to do bitwise operations or mean to do power operations.

Answer (score 2):

You must change your search strings to patterns to use the g (global search) option:

```
function evaluarExpresion (fx, x) {

    fx = fx.replace(/x/g, x)
    fx = fx.replace(/e/g, "Math.E")
    fx = fx.replace(/sin/g, "Math.sin")
    fx = fx.replace(/tan/g, "Math.tan")
    fx = fx.replace(/cos/g, "Math.cos")
    fx = fx.replace(/pi/g, "Math.PI")
    fx = fx.replace(/\*\*/g, "^")
    return eval(fx)
}

console.log(evaluarExpresion('(1**3)/(1+x**(1/2))' , 9));
```

Comment: Yeah! I just reckon. I need to to actually *replace all*